# Unexpected error in date?

Tags: php, date

I am getting an error as read below:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in X:\xampp\htdocs\lib.php on line 15
```

when I try and save the date to a variable.  Here is my code... (PHP)

```
protected $title = date('D, d M Y');
```

Comment: You can't assign a class variable with a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set your property defaults in the constructor:

```
class Something
{
    protected $title;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->title = date('D, d M Y');
    }

}
```